# Do Authentication and Authorization frameworks for Java that support openId exist (except Spring security)?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, jaas, jaspic

Actually I am interested in Java AA framework that supports many types of A&A.
I found that exist JAAS, but did not find any information about OpenId support. Maybe there exists a module to use it?
Spring Security supports OpenId but I just want to see any alternative. Also I read that Spring Security is a little bit complicated.

I think it is mostly common functionality and there must exist a way to simplify the developer's life and not force him to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: "A little bit complicated".... understatement of the evening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one.
It's a JSR-196 implementation.
Here's the link describing how to plugin OpenId4j to it: http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_serverauthmodule_jsr_196_with
But it's GlassFish oriented. I don't know how good it is with other Java EE App servers